# Android DataBinding with specific layout causes NullReferenceException

Tags: java, android, data-binding, nullpointerexception

I'm designing layout for Android DataBinding and encountered weird problem - after calling:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

I get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.spooksoft.testapp, PID: 11215

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spooksoft.testapp/com.spooksoft.testapp.activities.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

I managed to narrow down the code to minimum reproducible example.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.spooksoft.testapp.activities.MainActivity">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.spooksoft.testapp.viewmodels.MainActivityViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:hint="Login">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="@={viewModel.login}" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:hint="Email">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="@={viewModel.email}" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

MainActivityViewModel:

```
package com.spooksoft.testapp.viewmodels;

import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.ObservableBoolean;
import android.databinding.ObservableField;
import android.databinding.ObservableInt;

import com.spooksoft.testapp.viewmodels.interfaces.IMainActivityAccess;

public class MainActivityViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    // Private fields ---------------------------------------------------------

    private final ObservableField<String> login;
    private final ObservableField<String> email;

    private String registrationToken = null;

    public MainActivityViewModel() {

        login = new ObservableField<String>();
        email = new ObservableField<String>();
    }

    public ObservableField<String> getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public ObservableField<String> getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

ActivityMain:

```
package com.spooksoft.testapp.activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.spooksoft.testapp.R;
import com.spooksoft.testapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.spooksoft.testapp.viewmodels.MainActivityViewModel;
import com.spooksoft.testapp.viewmodels.interfaces.IMainActivityAccess;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Private fields ---------------------------------------------------------

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private MainActivityViewModel viewModel;

    // Protected methods ------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        viewModel = new MainActivityViewModel();
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
    }
}
```

If you want to reproduce the problem, remember to turn on the databinding library.

I will be very releaved to know, that I'm doing something wrong, but I fail to see, what. I copied bigger part of code containing very similar construct from other project in which everything works perfectly.

The complete error message looks like following:

```
09-11 19:53:55.052 5498-5498/pl.spooksoft.thermomixrecipes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: pl.spooksoft.thermomixrecipes, PID: 5498
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.spooksoft.thermomixrecipes/pl.spooksoft.thermomixrecipes.activities.RegisterActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
     at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:276)
     at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:261)
     at pl.spooksoft.thermomixrecipes.activities.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:38)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

---

**Edit:** Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:tag="layout/activity_main_0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context="com.spooksoft.testapp.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Login">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:tag="binding_1"            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Email">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:tag="binding_2"            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what does your layout look like in the final apk file? (use android studio analyze apk feature)

Comment: ok nevermind, seems i found `<view` in your layout

Comment: @pskink I included the output XML anyway.

Comment: ok so `<view` is your small animal you have to kill

Comment: @pskink Will do. Can you elaborate on that? Maybe it'll help someone else as well.

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#747, either use `<View` or `<view` with `class` attribute